# A question about bipartite graphs

Tags: graph-theory

Prove that there aren't any `bipartite graphs` with the sequence of grades

$s=\{6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,5,3,3,3,3,3\}$

I have no idea at this one.

Please,could you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

(1) How many total edges are there?

(2) Can you partition the vertices so that the correct number of edges originate in each set?

Comment: There are 68 edges there.

Comment: Please,could you give me more details about the second suggestion?

Comment: Each edge is counted twice in the sequence of degrees.

Comment: Aha, there are 34 edges there.

Comment: Well,there are 34 edges and 14 vertices.Please,could you tell me why we have a cycle with an odd length?